# How to go to a certain path (folder containing a certain file) in Total Commander?

Tags: shortcuts, path, total-commander

Let's say I have a certain - very long - path to a file (let's say: `c:\Documents and Settings\Username\Application Data\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\` )  and I would like to quickly access that directory in Total Commander. Is there any dialog box / keyboard shortcut which would allow me to simply paste the path there and enter that location, instead of the tedious process of digging into the directory tree?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you click twice on the top, where current path is displayed, it will change to edit field, where you can just enter new path and press Enter.

You can switch to edit mode if cursor is on the [..] and you press Shift+F6.

Another option is to write path into command line, preceding it with cd like this:

```
cd path_to_the_directory
```

then press enter.

Comment: re: `cd path_to_the_directory`: in his case, because the path contains spaces, he would have to quote it: `cd "c:\Documents and Settings\Username\Application Data\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\"`.

Comment: +1 for `cd` from command line.

Comment: Actually I checked it using TC 7.50a in Vista and Windows 7 and quotes are not needed even with spaces in the path. I'm speaking of TC command line of course. :)

Comment: Thanks, I don't know that great Shift+F6 shortcut :)

Comment: TC must have changed a lot since then, none of these work anymore

Comment: I tested and all three options still work in TC 10.00 in Windows 10.

Comment: So in practice `Home` and then subsequently `Shift+F6` does the job.

Answer (score 1):

If you find yourself browsing to a specific folder a lot of times, you can add it to the quickselect (the little button with the asterisk), you can add the current folder (optionally including the other pane folder), and you can manage this into a tree set of folders.

Answer (score 1):

Create tabs (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>) for folders you use often. 
Browse to the folder then right click on the tab and lock the tab.

The tabs are always shown when you start total commander it saves a lot of browsing to folders when you have created tabs for the most used folders.

Answer (score 0):

The selected answer doesn't work if you're in the root since there is no [..] there.

There is a keyboard shortcut you can assign to focus the path textbox: cm_EditPath.
Set a shortcut in Options -> Misc -> Redefine hotkeys

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).